# Prevent class methods overwritten in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have added a few personalized methods to the BaseContent class in Symfony
however there are other developers working on the Symfony app and probably they are having code generated by some sort of CRUD generator (I am not really familiar with Symfony so I am not sure what is being used).
The problem is that my bespoke code gets overwritten when the other developers re-generate the PHP classes.

Is there anything that can be done to keep the bespoke methods in the same BaseContent class file?

Comment: Talk to your colleagues to come to a consensus on what can and can't be overridden?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: Probably should implement some versioning software like svn.

Comment: @deceze it's not colleagues :)

Comment: Probably you can use [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword.

Comment: @deceze overwritten doesn't mean overridden. I read this to mean "the source of a class" is being overwritten by syfmony's code generator. Probably means the code is in the wrong place.

Comment: @AD7six OK, but if the code is being *overwritten*, physically, as in *source code changed*, then this question makes even less sense. No, you cannot protect source code from being changed if you give people access to it.

Comment: It makes sense in the world of symfony (which I know little about) - where to put code that ordinarily would go in <this file that gets autogenerated>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add or override BaseContent parameters and methods in your Content class, which is generated by symfony commands propel:build-model or doctrine:build-model(depending on which ORM you use), and located parent directory of the Base class. This so that when changing your schema you don't have to rewrite your personalized methods accordingly.

Propel example:

```
// lib/model/om/BaseContent.php
// Don't touch as it may be overwritten
abstract class BaseContent extends BaseObject  implements Persistent {
...
    public function getParameter()
    {
        return $this->parameter;
    }
...
}

// lib/model/Content.php
// add or override here
class Content extends BaseContent {
    public function getParameter()
    {
        //Do something more
        return parent::getParameter();
    }
}
```

Anywhere within your symfony project you always use the non-Base class, which inherits the base class.

Base classes are generated by PHP ORMs Propel (under folders 'om' and 'map') or Doctrine (under folder 'base') basing them on what is defined in your schema.

Comment: Exactly. You should never add anything to the base classes as they get overwritten. Keep all the code in the model class. If you need to override some base methods you can safely do it in the model class - it will still override the methods from the base class.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Model is not a class. A model is an abstraction layer. If you call something "Model" class, you end up violating the `SRP` and `LSP` at the same time

Comment: I agree that it is not quite accurate but I used this term here to refer to the `class Content` as opposed to the `class BaseContent`. I'll try to be more cautious when writing comments in the future :)